# Listing of a file with underscores in its name/path

Tags: listings, captions

I am writing a report with LaTeX and I need to list some source code. One of the files has some underscores in its path/name. When compiling the following line :

```
\lstinputlisting[label=source_code,caption=test_file.c]{abcd/test_file.c}
```

I get the following error :

> ! Package Listings Error: File `abcd/test\unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M
>   \hskip \ z@skip \unhbox \voidb@x \kern .06em\vbox {\hrule
>   width.3em}\discretionary {-}{} {}\penalty \@M \hskip \z@skip file(.c)'
>   not found.

The underscore is obviously not handled correctly, but I have not been able to find how to correct this so far (tried escaping it with "\_"). Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

**Test code (works in minimal version, stopped working with "underscore" package) :**

```
% Declarations
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{underscore}

% Code listing
\usepackage{listings}

% Begin document
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

Listing of test\_file.c :
\lstinputlisting{abcd/test_file.c}

\end{document}
```

**Answer**

The "underscore" package can help you when you have a lot of underscores to escape in your text, but you have to be careful with file names, cite or ref tags :

> The skips and penalties ruin any kerning with the underscore character
>   (when a character is used). However, there doesn’t seem to be much, if
>   any, such kerning in the EC fonts, and there is never any kerning with
>   a rule. You must avoid “_” in file names and in cite or ref tags, or
>   you must use the babel package, with its active-character controls, or
>   you must give the [strings] option, which attempts to redefine several
>   commands (and may not work perfectly). Even without the [strings]
>   option or babel, you can use occasional underscores like:
>   “\include{file\string_name}”.

([Source](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underscore/underscore.pdf))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the underscore in the `caption` argument, but *not* in the mandatory argument:

```
lstinputlisting[label=source_code,caption=test\_file.c]{abcd/test_file.c}
%                                            ^^^^^             ^^^^^
```

Comment: I already tried this and it did not work. I should have said this in the description :-s

Comment: OK, fixed. Only escape the `caption` argument.

Comment: It still does not work for me. I've tried "\lstinputlisting{abcd/test\_file.c}" as a minimum command, with or without escaping the underscore, and I still get the same error. Could it have something to do with the encoding packages I use? ([utf8x]{inputenc}, [french]{babel})

Comment: I can't reproduce that; it all works fine for me, with or without those packages... are you using a custom font package?

Comment: Can you try with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Same thing with pdflatex.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete example somewhere?

Comment: Example added to the initial post.

Comment: My answer stands; *don't* escape the underscore in the argument.

Comment: @BenC: The wonders of making a *minimal* example. You're forced to localizing the error! :-)

Comment: Works now, and I just found the package that created the problem in the first place : "underscore" (yeah I know, even if I had ~30 packages, how could I miss this one?). I just found [this](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underscore/underscore.pdf) : "You must avoid “_” in file names and in cite or ref tags, or you must use the babel package, with its active-character controls, or you must give the [strings] option, which attempts to redefine several commands (and may not work perfectly)"

Comment: Haha. The joys, eh?

Comment: No worries - I've had more of my share of LaTeX worries myself, I empathize :-)