# How do I escape an underscore in the caption of a code listing, within a macro?

Tags: macros, listings, code, underscore

I use this macro to include Matlab code in my document:

```
\newrobustcmd{\inputmatlabcode}[1]{\lstinputlisting[basicstyle={\scriptsize \ttfamily}, caption=#1, language = matlab]{#1}}
```

It fails when I try to include code files with underscores in their names. I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35204) but since I'm referring to the file name in both the caption and the argument to listings, and only need to escape the underscore in the caption.

The `underscore` package will break the rest of my document, I think, so I'm trying to avoid using that.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you don't need `underscore` package. You can use `\detokenize` to process underscores properly:

If you create a `hello_world.m` file with some lines in your work directory, here is an MWE (also I'd like to remind you to attach an MWE when you're asking a question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\inputmatlabcode[1]{
  \lstinputlisting[
    basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
    caption=\detokenize{#1},
    language=matlab
  ]{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\inputmatlabcode{hello_world.m}
\end{document}
```

The result will be like:
[image]